# BitmapImage and Image components does not display loaded bitmap?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4.5

```
[Bindable]
protected var bmp : Bitmap = new Bitmap();
...

var loader : Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, onComplete );
    loader.load( new URLRequest( fileObj.url ) );

function onComplete( event : Event ) : void
{
    trace( Bitmap( LoaderInfo( event.target ).content ).bitmapData.height );

    bmp = ( new Bitmap( Bitmap( LoaderInfo( event.target ).content ).bitmapData ) ) ;

}
...

<s:BitmapImage id="cameraSource" width="100%" height="100%" source="{ bmp }" scaleMode="stretch" />
```

I am using this source code to load a localy stored image file.
It is loaded fine, but due some reason is not displayed.

- Why the follow source code doesn't display the loaded image ?

*// Flex 4.6 and Flex 4.8 tested, mobile AIR application*

Comment: Your code works in a web app. The only thing I changed was the URL to the image. Note the comments in the [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html) about iOS -- is the problem only occurring on an iOS device? The only thing I noticed is that your `loader` variable seems to be a local one, and potentially could be garbage collected. But I think you'd get a null pointer error in your event handler if that was the case.

Comment: It is on Android emulator under Windows. The code appears to works if i switch to protected function onComplete, anyway - I am still not getting any image as result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like It is my fault of not sufficient explaining the situation.
The whole thing is moved into a View, but once a browse for picture view is been pushed, it is destroying the data into current view.

The follow row of code is fixing everything

```
destructionPolicy="never"
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone that helped on this very stuck topic. Your helped actually more than sufficient to finally end to the conclusion that something else i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Best guess is that your binding isn't triggering an update, try assigning the property directly

```
cameraSource.source = bmp; //at the end of onComplete
```

Either this or the container for the BitmapImage is constraining it's size, you could also try setting a literal explicit pixel size temporarily instead of a percent.

Comment: You can also set the `source` to the `URLRequest` object directly.

Comment: tried both ways. the result remains the same - the image is loaded but not shown.

Comment: @YordanYanakiev I think you should try to set a static source to be sure your able to see the image if there are no problems with the source.  If you're having layout issues any amount of debugging/tweaking on the source isn't going to show us that.

Comment: well, you've got me mostly stumped.  I've also been working on a mobile AIR app (pure as3 though) and have an occasional issue with very large images that are supposed to load from the CameraRoll not loading in but haven't investigated it much yet.  As I address that issue in the next couple of days I'll post back if I find anything peculiar specific to mobile (also have you fiddled with the renderMode at all? gpu renderMode caused some DOs to not show up on me)

Comment: Thanks :) I will wait for a words of you. About the GPU - I haven't switched anything. It's on default settings.

Comment: Hmm, so turns out I was wrong about it being a file size issue, even with large photo sphere images they load up fine.  The issue I was encountering was loading from the CameraRoll if the image is from Picasa the load fails (probably because the full file isn't local, dunno).  For your issue have you been running in debug mode, I ask because the docs mention the possibility of a security violation with loading data vs content, and I wonder if it's treating this as the former when you're manually loading it.

Comment: Consider other source options http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/primitives/BitmapImage.html#source